# tooltip to show single element of group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: Example attached]I have a bar chart and  I have text values at the end of each bar. What I would like to do is set text to invisible, and on `mouseover` I'd like it to show the number associated with the bar, at the magnitude of that bar.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in an efficient manner.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d,i){
        return yScale(i);
    })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", function(d,i){
        return xScale(d);
    })
    .attr("height", h/dataset.length)
    .style("fill", function(d,i){
        return colors(d);
    })

.on("mouseover", function(d){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.5)
    tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1);

    tooltip.html(d)
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
})

.on("mouseout", function(d){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1)
    tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0)
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery too?

Comment: So does your code work for you or not? I don't see any efficiency problems with it?

Comment: the code does not work, short of hard coding specific text values to display at a single, hard-coded location.  i want the text values to display at the length of each bar, whatever that length may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`, I recommend doing it with `$(this).hover` and `$(this).mousemove`. Try something like this:

```
$(this).hover(
    function() {
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1)

            // In order to trigger the magnitude or 'width' of the rect:
            var rectWidth = $(this).attr("width");
    }, function () {
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    }
);

/*$(this).mousemove(function(event) {
    tooltip
        .style("left", event.clientX + "px")
        .style("top", event.clientY + "px")
});*/
```

Comment: how can I use $(this).hover to show a single bar text value? as opposed to the who group of text values?

Comment: Is `dataset` the group of text values? Is it an array or a json?

Comment: it is an array of 12 randomly generated numbers.

Comment: If you add an example of the array into your question, and specify which number you want, I can add that functionality to my answer.

Comment: I added a picture in my original post.  I would like the numbers to show in their exact location, but only one at a time (on mouseover).

Comment: Slight confusion. Right now, the numbers should have `opacity:0` on them. Is that style not being applied? Also, having a `.mousemove` binding would mean that the tooltip follows the mouse, and will only be displayed when you hover over a `rect`. I'm guessing you don't want that anymore?

Comment: I displayed the numbers to show where I want them located. I dont want the number to follow the mouse.  I want the mouse entering a rect to trigger the magnitude of that rect to display with .attr("x", function(d){return xScale(d)} , but that doesnt work

Comment: You can find the width with `$(this).attr("width")` in the `.hover` event.